# How to secure Neo4J replication?

Tags: neo4j

I need to secure the replication data stream between two Neo4J nodes (eg. using SSL or TLS). Both are running in embedded mode in two JBoss instances.

Is it possible and how can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Neo4j replication is not encrypted by itself. The most easy way would be connecting the cluster members using a VPN (e.g. using [openvpn](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/overview.html)) and configure Neo4j to use the virtual network interface provided by the VPN.

An alternative might be [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html).

#### Update:

there is a [nice blog post](http://toolongdidntread.com/neo4j/replicating-over-a-vpn-with-a-simple-neo4j-masterslave-setup/) on using openvpn for encrypting Neo4j cluster replication by John Russell. Please note that this uses Neo4j <= 1.8, in Neo4j 1.9.x there is no Zookeeper any more.